# How to display the full text in the button ipywidget?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am creating an `ipywidget` button with some text. But the full text is not shown in the button:

[image]

The code I have used is as follows:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
button = widgets.Button(
    description='Test button with some text.',
    disabled=False,
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='column',
    align_items='stretch'
)        
display(button)
```

What options to use so the full text is shown in the button (i.e. to make the button width increase so the full text is shown)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create an object of the `Layout` class and use it as an attribute to style width/height for different widgets. You can read more about it [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Layout-and-Styling-of-Jupyter-widgets). The properties defined in `Layout` are CSS properties. Therefore, to fit text to button width, just set `width='auto'`.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

layout = widgets.Layout(width='auto', height='40px') #set width and height

button = widgets.Button(
    description='Test button with some text.',
    disabled=False,
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='column',
    align_items='stretch', 
    layout = layout
)        
display(button)
```

[image]

Lets increase the `description` length:

```
description='Test button with some text and some more'
```

[image]

You can re-use the layout property on other widgets too:

```
widgets.Button(description='Another button with the same layout', layout=button.layout)
```

Comment: But now I have extra space on both sides. Ideally I want the text to fill out the space, i.e. so much space as the text is long.

Comment: ok, I've just edited my answer. The `width` should be set to `auto`.

Answer (score 17):

Add `style= {'description_width': 'initial'}`

```
button = widgets.Button(
    description='Test button with some text.',
    disabled=False,
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='column',
    align_items='stretch', 
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}
)
```

Comment: Try `width: initial`.